# Two-Dimensional ArrayList set an element

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this piece of code:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> tree = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

tree.add(0, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1)));
tree.add(1, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,3)));
tree.add(2, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6)));
```

I would like, for example, to replace 5 with 9. how can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use

```
tree.get(2).set(1,Integer.valueOf(9));
```

to get the ArrayList at the position 2 and then set the second element to 9.

Answer (score 2):

```
tree.get(2).set(1, 9)
```

This gets the third (i.e. index = 2) element of the outer ArrayList, which returns the inner ArrayList. Then set the 2nd element (index = 1) to 9. Autoboxing takes care of the int to Integer conversion.

Answer (score 1):

find index of elements that you want to replace and use twice [set(index, newElement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)
 method to do the replacement

Answer (score 0):

### The major methods we use in a 2-Dimensional ArrayList are -->

let say we have a 2-Dimensional ArrayList as

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ArrayList_2D = new ArrayList<>()
```

To find the size

```
ArrayList_2D.size();
```

To access some element at position (i , j)

```
ArrayList_2D.get(i).get(j);
```

To set value of an element at position (i , j) equal to x

```
ArrayList_2D.get(i).set(j , x);
```

To remove (i , j) element

```
ArrayList_2D.get(i).remove(j);
```

To find the index of first occurring of element y

```
 int col , row;
 for(int a=0;a<ArrayList_2D.size();a++){
     for(int b=0;b<ArrayList_2D.size();b++){
         if(ArrayList_2D.get(i).get(j)==y){
                 col = i;
                 row = j;
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Hope This Is Will Be HelpFul**

Comment: Too much irrelevant information.