# Changing a custom number in an ListArray[String]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a ArrayList containing numbers, separated by spaces and endlines, basically with regex:\d+

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Users input 2 numbers: 1 number for the row(line) and second number for the column(index).
So if there are 3 lines

> 1111 2222 33333
>
> 4444444 42345234 32424
>
> 23 453435 3452345 2435234

and the user types in 0 and then types in 2 he would get the number

> 33333

The input is done here:

```
int[] i = new int[2];
System.out.print("Enter a line for the number:");
i[0] = s.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the index of the number in that line:");
i[1] = s.nextInt();
```

What I'm trying to do is get that number the user has inserted it and replace it with another number.
I have this:

```
String[] firstLine = list.get(i[0]); //Contains the whole row(line)
int index = i[1]; //Need to make this connect to firstLine. Make it a column(index)
```

So, this will get the first line and then get the index of the line by the user's instructions, right?

Now I'm trying to use .set to replace the number:

```
list.set(i[0][index], randomNum);
```

To sum up my quesion. What do I do:

```
list.set(HERE, randomNum);
```

to make the list.set recognize what position I'm trying to change?

I hope you understood this and will help me. Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855154/two-dimensional-arraylist-set-an-element).

Comment: wat, this is not a duplicate, I searched for an hour before I posted this...

Comment: How is that not a duplicate? The answer is the same -- get the row, change the value.

Comment: Because the rows here have columns and my question was specifically directed to the columns. Why are you such a hater? How am I supposed to learn If there are people like you?

Comment: I can't see any difference. Also [Why do people take downvotes so personally?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally) | Calling me a hater seems a bit... not nice.

Comment: @user202729 The only difference is this is a *List of arrays* whereas that is *List of List*.

Comment: @Sibuscus Nobody hates you - All are here trying to help you

Comment: @user7 Which is not a significant factor. Both are modifiable objects.

Comment: (you can flag if you find a comment violating the ["Be Nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice))

Comment: @user202729 True. But this cannot be closed as a duplicate of that. Maybe, can get an idea from that

Comment: As to why I take the downvotes so personally: Imagine going somewhere where you are new and people don't like what you say and they can express that in downvotes. Well, downvotes discourage me from asking more and I consider this to be a legit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a one-dimensional array and hence you cannot write `i[0][index]`.

Since you already have the *reference* to the first row (array), you can simply do

```
firstLine[index] = randomNum; //Assuming randomNum is a String
```

*EDIT:* Since you have already modified the first row, there is no need to set it. If you do, it would look like

```
list.set(i[0], firstLine);
```

where,

*i[0]* is the row number and

`firstLine` is the value (array)

Comment: DUde, I know that, my question here is what do I type at .set(HERE, randomNum)

Comment: @Sibuscus You need to differentiate between reference and value.

Comment: To your new EDIT: If I do that, it will just replace THE WHOLE ROW. I'm trying to replace ONE NUMBER that the user has specified. There are rows and columns in my ArrayList<String[]>

Comment: *I'm trying to replace ONE NUMBER* - that's exactly what you do in `firstLine[index] = randomNum;`

Comment: If you have a 2D array (`String[][]`) you can access it like `array[i][j]`. But what you have here is a `List of arrays` which you need to access (the individual element) as `list.get(<rowNumber>)[columnNumber]`

Comment: Oh, yeah, wait, I misunderstood you. I'll try it. Who keeps downvoting me, what rules am I breaking?